# Meteor.Collection with Meteor.bindEnvironment

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

Within a function that is already within Meteor.binEnvironment, when I run `<collection>.find ({})`, I get the error `throw new Error ('Can \' t wait without a fiber ');` 
If you place that call also within `Meteor.bindEnvironment(<collection>.find ({}))`, the error message becomes: `throw new Error (noFiberMessage);`

The function in question runs through `Meteor.methods ({})`
Where am I going wrong?

Example to reproduce the error:

```
Meteor.methods({
  "teste" : Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
    var Future = Meteor.require('fibers/future');
    var future = new Future();
    setTimeout(function(){
      return future.return(Sessions.findOne({}))
    }, 15000);
    console.log('fut', future.wait());
  })
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this solves your actual problem, but in your example, there's no need to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment`, just use `Meteor.setTimeout` instead of `setTimeout` (`Meteor.setTimeout` will use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` under the hood for you).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Meteor._wrapAsync` instead.

This is an example of an async function, but any other would do:

```
var asyncfunction = function(callback) {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
        callback(null, Sessions.findOne({}))
    }, 15000);
}

var syncfunction = Meteor._wrapAsync(asyncfunction);

var result = syncfunction();

console.log(result);
```

You could wrap any asynchronous function and make it synchronous and bind the fibers with it this way.

Comment: I could not apply the suggested solution in my project, currently do this way:

    `Meteor.methods({
      "teste" : Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
        var Fiber = Meteor.require('fibers');
        var Future = Meteor.require('fibers/future');
        var future = new Future();
        setTimeout(function(){
          return future.return(
            Fiber(function(){
              Sessions.findOne({});
            }).run()
          );
        }, 15000);
        console.log('fut', future.wait());
      })
    });`

Answer (score 1):

I could not apply the suggested solution in my project, currently do this way:

```
Meteor.methods({
  "teste" : Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
    var Fiber = Meteor.require('fibers');
    var Future = Meteor.require('fibers/future');
    var future = new Future();
    setTimeout(function(){
      return future.return(
        Fiber(function(){
          Sessions.findOne({});
        }).run()
      );
    }, 15000);
    console.log('fut', future.wait());
  })
});
```