# [ 'Parse error: Can\'t wait without a fiber' ]' When trying to do find within Metor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, websocket, find, fiber

When receiving JSON data via websockets, I'm trying to feed this data into a mongodb within meteor. I'm getting the JSON data fine, but when trying to find whether the data already exists in the database, I keep getting the error: "[ 'Parse error: Can\'t wait without a fiber' ]'.

```
binance.websockets.miniTicker(markets => {
      //we've got the live information from binance
      if (db.Coins.find({}).count() === 0) {
        //if there's nothing in the database right now
        markets.forEach(function(coin) {
          //for each coin in the JSON file, create a new document
          db.Coins.insert(coin);
        });
      }
    });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this cleared up?

Many thanks,
Rufus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute a mongo operation within an async function's callback. This callback is not bound to the running fiber anymore. In order to connect the callback to a fiber you need to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` which binds the fiber to the callback.

```js
binance.websockets.miniTicker(Meteor.bindEnvironment((markets) => {
  //we've got the live information from binance
  if (db.Coins.find({}).count() === 0) {
    //if there's nothing in the database right now
    markets.forEach(function(coin) {
      //for each coin in the JSON file, create a new document
      db.Coins.insert(coin);
    });
  }
}));
```

You should not require to bind to the function within the `forEach` as they are not async.

Related posts on SO:

[Meteor.Collection with Meteor.bindEnvironment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134897/meteor-collection-with-meteor-bindenvironment)

[Meteor: Calling an asynchronous function inside a Meteor.method and returning the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569712/meteor-calling-an-asynchronous-function-inside-a-meteor-method-and-returning-th)

[Meteor wrapAsync or bindEnvironment without standard callback signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391067/meteor-wrapasync-or-bindenvironment-without-standard-callback-signature)

[What's going on with Meteor and Fibers/bindEnvironment()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994951/whats-going-on-with-meteor-and-fibers-bindenvironment)